# Finding near by devices on local Wi-Fi network for Windows Store multiplayer game

Tags: c++, networking, windows-8.1, multiplayer

I have developed a game for Windows Store in Visual Studio 2013 using C++ and DirectX(Xaml) template by referring 3D Starterkit project sample. Now I want to implement a local multiplayer feature so that users can play it real time on two Windows Devices connected to local wireless network. I am new to Windows Platform and networking concepts. I searched on Windows Developer Centre for browsing near by devices running same application. I found two samples viz. Proximity Sample and WiFiDirectDevice Sample. But these samples are not able to find near by devices. I would like to have suggestions for following:

1) Will the "Proximity" or the "WiFiDirectDevice" sample meet my requirements of browsing near by devices on local network running the same application?

2) Are there any other better approaches for browsing near by devices running the same application?
I'd appreciate any suggestions on these queries. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use the native WiFi interface to do this. Please refer to teh below URL https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706275(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Would it be sufficient to have your program periodically send out a UDP broadcast packet on a well known port, and also listen on that port for any UDP packets sent by other instances of your program?  Using recvfrom() to receiving incoming UDP packets would give you the IP addresses of any other instances on the LAN, and any other information you want to communicate could be included in the UDP packet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WlanGetAvailableNetworkList method from native WiFI API to get the list of available networks. Also you can host a Soft Access point and allow another client to join using the  native WiFI API.

```
dwResult = WlanGetAvailableNetworkList(hClient,
                                                 &pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid,
                                                 0, 
                                                 NULL, 
                                                 &pBssList);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706749(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you for suggestions @JTsunami

Comment: Will this API work for ARM devices (Surface RT) also? I tried using this approach in my code, but I am getting identifier not found or undefined identifier errors for wlanapi methods and variables. I have included wlanapi.h" file and also `#pragma comment(lib, "wlanapi.lib")"` in the code. Still it is showing errors. I found that the wlanapi.lib file is not showing up in the Additional Dependency of the project in Linker Input properties section of Visual Studio. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The above API won't work on WIN RT or windows store apps. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getconnectionprofiles.aspx This may work for you on WinRT devices, Not sure though.

Comment: Thank you @JTsunami. In that case I would like to go with the UDP approach suggested by JeremyFriesner.